# call up title not smooth with imported video

Tags: adobe-premiere

I have build call up title using adobe premier software. Unfortunately, all call-up titles don't appear smooth on the video. Please see the image below:

[image]

Any Advice.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the playback that is not smooth? I noticed you have the resolution at full what happens if you put this down to half or a quarter? if the playback is running normally you could add a very small amount of motion blur and that should help with the jitteriness.

Ideally, I would need to see the final video to make real-world suggestions that would fix the animations.